# Adding textfield input to array during forEach in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I'm new to Swift / SwiftUI and trying to store the textfield value in an array during a foreach. However I'm encountering a **Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range** message. Should the storing the value happen outside the view(View Model) or can it be done inside a View??

```
struct OrderView: View {
    
    @Binding var groupsize: Int
    
    @State var nameArray = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
            
            VStack {          
                
                ForEach(0 ..< groupsize) { index in
                    TextField("Insert name", text: $nameArray[index])}
                
            }
              
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not replace `groupsize` with `nameArray.count`?

Comment: This is since the number of values I want to store depends on the ```groupsize``` variable that comes from the previous view.

Comment: `groupsize` > `nameArray.count` which is the problem here

Comment: Do `ForEach(0 ..< groupsize - 1)`, but as @George_E mentioned, this might not be a good design choice

Comment: @aheze This doesn't work

Comment: your `nameArray` is empty, and you trying to access its nonexisting values. it should be prepopulated with empty strings

Answer (score 3):

taking all the good advice of the comments, you could try something like this:

```
struct OrderView: View {
    @Binding var groupsize: Int
    @State var nameArray = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if nameArray.count > 0 {
                ForEach(0 ..< groupsize) { index in
                    TextField("Insert name", text: $nameArray[index])}
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            if groupsize > 0 {
                nameArray = [String](repeating: "", count: groupsize)
            }
        })
    }
}
```